# Acrobat Signatures?

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-scripting

Not sure if this is the proper place for this question but I'm sure some of us have had to deal with creating these types of forms. I know how to add a "digital signature" field to my Acrobat document. The issue is when I send the document out as is, the user is prompted with a somewhat complex process of creating a digital signature. Is there a dead-simple way to just have the user type in their name and have it appear as a mock signature (script typeface)? Yet, make it feel like they are officially signing the document. I have had official documents sent to me in the past and all I had to do was either type my name or click and it would fill in the signature field automatically without having to create a digital signature. Perhaps creating a plain field can do the trick but doesn't seem official as dumb as that sounds. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason you haven't had to set up a digital signature certificate is probably because you have already done it.  You only have to create it once and then it is stored in your computer for future use (I think, possibly linked to an online thing, I can't remember exactly).  For your customers, it would be the same.  The digital signature is actually linked to a certificate that gets embedded in the document when they "sign" that validates the signature.

Adobe has a great explanation [here](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/sign/digital-signatures.html) on how it works and some of the options.

However, if you don't want to mess with any of that, you can just use the field, and set it to use a script font.  just make sure that the ENTIRE font is embedded when you save the PDF or it won't work right.

Thanks @Max Wyss! Adding from the comments so no one misses it!

> When you select a font for a (text) field, it gets fully embedded; you'd have to make sure that this is possible. **HOWEVER**, "signing" with a script font is not a digital signature!! Well, as long as your "signature" does not need to be legally binding, it is fine, but you won't be able to hold (or defend) any claims in court.

Comment: When you select a font for a (text) field, it gets fully embedded; you'd have to make sure that this is possible. HOWEVER, "signing" with a script font is not a digital signature!! Well, as long as your "signature" does not need to be legally binding, it is fine, but you won't be able to hold (or defend) any claims in court.

Comment: I know how signatures work in terms of setting one up. I've already set one up in the past for personal applications. This particular project wasn't meant to be a legally binding document. It was meant more to be a document that had tones of being legally binding but more of a mutual understanding between the two parties. We ended up just making the font a different color and a bit larger.  Thank you all for weighing in and it's appreciated.